# MySQL - granting permission

Tags: mysql

I don't get how to give a user permissions in MySQL.

I am using MySQL RDS on aws. I am creating a user and need access to the reports database.
  I created a hash password and ran the below.

```
SELECT PASSWORD('Test123');

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON reports.* TO 'central'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*D1AD25EDF929F55FBFF703358EC527';


mysql -u central -pTest123 -h test.com
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'central'@'112.198.130.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

Why?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You granted permission to `'central'@'localhost'` but are attempting to authenticate as `'central'@'112.198.130.xxx'`.  Either connect from `localhost`, or grant permission to the appropriate hosts.

Comment: so... if the server is in test.com then 'central'@'test.com'?

Comment: @Tampa: No, if the client is connecting from `1.2.3.4` then `'central'@'1.2.3.4'`.